# xl2tpd-control command not working

Tags: router, ipsec, l2tp

I have an cisco vpn server which which i am trying to connect an endpoint through VPN(IPsec/L2TP). I have strongswan, xl2tpd and pppd running on my machine. IPsec conection is established successfully and i verified it by command "ipsec statusall" but sometimes command i use for l2tp connection is not working. Following are the commands which i am running for l2tp connection:

xl2tpd -c /etc/xl2tpd.conf -C /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control

xl2tpd-control add l2tp lns=10.0.97.5

xl2tpd-control add l2tp local ip =10.0.97.74

xl2tpd-control connect l2tp A A

This does not seem to send any packet to router, I have checked router logs also. I have also used wireshark at endpoint but no packets are sent for l2tp connection. I don't know what is missing.

Note: this behaviour is not consistent, it is occurring a few times only.

Comment: I just want to add one observation, generally whenever i used to fire following commands, i used to get 00 OK on console:
xl2tpd-control add l2tp lns=10.0.97.5

xl2tpd-control add l2tp local ip =10.0.97.74

xl2tpd-control connect l2tp A A

but when 00 OK is not displayed on the console then endpoint does not send any l2tp packets to cisco router.

Comment: my xl2tpd-control returns 253...